# JSOUP - Accessing elements within a div class / stop when reaching a specific div class

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I'm trying to parse data from HTML. I need to get specific content from the html code which the ordering or the html content may be different.

```
<h1>Latest Deals</h1>\r\n </div>\r\n </div>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n
<div class=\"breadcrumb-wrapper\">\r\n    
<ul class=\"breadcrumb\">\r\n        
<li><a href=\"/Home\">Home</a></li>\r\n        
<li><a href=\"/Deals\">Deals</a></li>\r\n        
<li class=\"active\">Mau Mudik Hemat? Nikmati Diskon Hingga 20%</li>\r\n 
</ul>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n
<div class=\"article outer clearfix\">\r\n    
<div class=\"col-sm-12\">\r\n        
<img alt=\"Mau Mudik Hemat? Nikmati Diskon Hingga 20%\" title=\"Mau Mudik Hemat? Nikmati Diskon Hingga 20%\" src=\"/images/slider/id/special-raya-offer-id-v2.jpg\">\r\n        
<h1>Mau Mudik Hemat? Nikmati Diskon Hingga 20%</h1>\r\n        
<p class=\"date\">May 18th, 2018</p>\r\n        
<p><strong class=\"text-red\"></strong></p>\r\n\r\n        
<p>This is the first paragraph</p>\r\n\r\n        
<p>This is the second paragraph.</p>\r\n\r\n        
<p>This is the third paragraph</p>\r\n\r\n        
<p>Below is the point form start:</p>\r\n\r\n        
<ol>\r\n            
<li>Point form A</li>\r\n            
<li>Point form B</li>\r\n            
<li>Point form C</li>\r\n            
<li>Point form D</li>\r\n            
</ol>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n        
<div class=\"m-top30 m-bottom20\">\r\n    
<a href=\"/home\" class=\"btn btn-lg btn-orange\">Home</a>\r\n\r\n    \r\n\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n\r\n
```

Previously i had successfully get the content i want via:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
Element eTitle = doc.getElementsByTag("h1").get(1);
Elements eBody = doc.getElementsByTag("p");

for (Element body : eBody) {
   detailContent += "<p>" + body.html() + "</p>";
```

The code above i getting the first "h1" and all element with "p" from my long html code. However, now in some case i might have element "ol" in between of those "p". For example:

```
<div class=\"col-sm-12\">\r\n <img alt=\"abc\" title=\"abcd\" src=\"/images/slider/id/abcd.jpg\">\r\n 
<h1>This is the header</h1>\r\n
<p class=\"date\">November 4th, 2015</p>\r\n 
<p><strong class=\"text-red\">Sorry, this promotion has expired.</strong></p>\r\n  
<p> Paragraph 1 </p>\r\n
<p> Paragraph 2 </p>\r\n
<ol>\r\n            
<li> Point 1 </li>\r\n            
<li> Point 2 </li>\r\n            
</ol>\r\n
<p> Paragraph 3 </p>\r\n
<p> Paragraph 4 </p>\r\n
<ol>\r\n            
<li> Point 1 </li>\r\n            
<li> Point 2 </li>\r\n            
</ol>\r\n
<div class=\"m-top30 m-bottom20\">
```

How should i create my code to get all these item?

*P.s All i want to do is 

1) To get the element in "col-sm-12" div / the last element before "m-top30 m-bottom20"

2) Ignore certain element contain in "col-sm-12"

Comment: @Shown, can you post the actual html fragment?

Comment: the html is actually a long string return from API. I had edit the question for full html content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the selectors to CSS and adding the filter such as 'p' under the first div can help you. However from the above html it is not clear whether the first div ends before the starting of the second div. If you share more details about the html, may be we can refine the selectors. I have stated the assumptions/my understanding in the code comment.

```
    String eTitle = doc.select("div.col-sm-12 > h1").text(); //I'm assuming you are trying to fetch the title text. 

    Elements eBody = doc.select("div.col-sm-12 > p , ol"); //This CSS selector will limit the 'p' elements to this div alone. 

    for (Element body : eBody) {
      //work with the 'body' element here.
```

Comment: Hi, the html is actually a long "string" return from API Json content. I cant do any changes from the html string. So just try out any method i can just get the correct item i want to use

Comment: Btw, your answer had no diff with what i working on, it get the <p> item, but in some case i will have <ol> in between the <p>, with this case it will ignore the <ol> which i dont hope to. I want to get all the <p> & <ol> in its correct order

Comment: I misunderstood your needs, I thought you wanted to remove 'ol' :-) I have edited and included that in the current selection. Please check and revert back if that meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Krishna, the code works for me!
Btw, a quick question here, for the .select(p, ol) it will select the p & ol element and add into eBody like FIFO or will select all element in P first then OL next?

Comment: @Shawn I think it does in FIFO manner. I did few experiments to conclude that. I could not locate any documented ref. to validate it.

Comment: Yup, found this out also from my own test. Thanks again!